# Saving and retrieving data

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

This program needs to be able to store the information provided and retrievable. What i would like to happen is when the save button is clicked it will save the data and when the edit button is clicked it fills the table with the information save. And i tried to add a scroll bar. The Save button command is at line 379 the edit button is at 357
and the scroll bar is at line 100 I know my code is terrible but i'm a beginner and its the best i have so far. Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

public class IAdvise extends JFrame {

   DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
   String[] columnNames = {"ID", "NAME", "COURSE", "Professor", "Reason for Tutor", "Login Time", "Logout Time"};
   Object[][] data = new Object[30][7];

   // table
   JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames) {
        @Override
      public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
         return false;
      }
   };
   JFrame frame, frame1;
   JPanel buttonPanel, buttonPanel2, tablePanel, addPanel, editPanel;
   JLabel labelID, labelName, labelCourse, labelProfessor, labelHelp, labelDate, labelDate2;
   JTextField txtID, txtName, txtCourse, txtProfessor, txtHelp, txtDate, txtDate2;
   JButton btnAdd, btnEdit, btnDelete, btnSort, btnSave, btnAddInput, btnCancel;
   int keyCode, rowIndex, rowNumber, noOfStudents;
   IAdvise.ButtonHandler bh = new IAdvise.ButtonHandler();


   public IAdvise() {
      table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
      table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new IAdvise.RowListener());
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(150);
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(100);
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(200);
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(150);
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(150);


      table.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
      table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

      btnAdd = new JButton("Login");
      btnAdd.addActionListener(bh);
      btnEdit = new JButton("EDIT");
      btnEdit.addActionListener(bh);
      btnEdit.setEnabled(false); 
      btnDelete = new JButton("DELETE");
      btnDelete.addActionListener(bh);
      btnDelete.setEnabled(false);
      btnSort = new JButton("Logout");
      btnSort.addActionListener(bh);
      btnSave = new JButton("SAVE");
      btnSave.addActionListener(bh);
      btnSave.setActionCommand("Save");


      btnAddInput = new JButton("Login");
      btnAddInput.addActionListener(bh);
      btnAddInput.setActionCommand("AddInput");
      btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
      btnCancel.addActionListener(bh);

      labelID = new JLabel("ID");
      labelName = new JLabel("NAME");
      labelCourse = new JLabel("Course");
      labelProfessor = new JLabel("Professor");
      labelHelp = new JLabel("Reason for Tutoring");
      labelDate = new JLabel("Login");
      labelDate2 = new JLabel("Logout");
      txtID = new JTextField(20);
      txtName = new JTextField(20);
      txtCourse = new JTextField(20);
      txtProfessor = new JTextField(20);
      txtHelp = new JTextField(20);
      txtDate = new JTextField(20);
      txtDate2 = new JTextField(20);
      txtID.setDocument(new IAdvise.JTextFieldLimit(15)); 

      txtID.addKeyListener(keyListener); 

      tablePanel = new JPanel();
      tablePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(tablePanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
      tablePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 2, 0, 10));
      tablePanel.add(table.getTableHeader());
      tablePanel.add(table);
      JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(tablePanel);
      scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
      scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
      scrollPane.setBounds(50, 30, 300, 50);
      JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(null);
      contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
      contentPane.add(scrollPane);



      buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 0;
      c.ipady = 20;
      c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      buttonPanel.add(btnAdd, c);
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 1;
      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      c.ipady = 20;
      c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
      buttonPanel.add(btnEdit, c);
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 2;
      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      c.ipady = 20;
      c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
      buttonPanel.add(btnDelete, c);
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 3;
      c.ipady = 20;
      c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      buttonPanel.add(btnSort, c);
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 4;
      c.ipady = 20;
      c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      buttonPanel.add(btnSave, c);


      frame = new JFrame("Tutoring Database");
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.add(tablePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
      frame.pack();

      addPanel = new JPanel();
      addPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

      c.insets = new Insets(1, 0, 1, 1);
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 0;
      addPanel.add(labelID, c);
      c.gridy = 1;
      addPanel.add(labelName, c);
      c.gridy = 2;
      addPanel.add(labelCourse, c);
      c.gridy = 3;
      addPanel.add(labelProfessor, c);
      c.gridy = 4;
      addPanel.add(labelHelp, c);
      c.gridy = 5;
      addPanel.add(labelDate, c);
      c.gridy = 6;
      addPanel.add(labelDate2, c);
      // text fields
      c.gridx = 1;
      c.gridy = 0;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtID, c);
      c.gridy = 1;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtName, c);
      c.gridy = 2;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtCourse, c);
      c.gridy = 3;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtProfessor, c);
      c.gridy = 4;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtHelp, c);
      c.gridy = 5;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtDate, c);
      c.gridy = 5;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtDate2, c);

      buttonPanel2 = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
      buttonPanel2.add(btnAddInput);
      buttonPanel2.add(btnCancel);

      frame1 = new JFrame("Student Database");
      frame1.setVisible(false);
      frame1.setResizable(false);
      frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame1.add(addPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      frame1.add(buttonPanel2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
      frame1.pack();
   }// end

   KeyListener keyListener = new KeyListener() {
        @Override
      public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
      }

        @Override
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
         keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

         if (!(keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) && !(keyCode >= 96 && keyCode <= 105)
                  && !(keyCode >= 37 && keyCode <= 40) && !(keyCode == 127 || keyCode == 8)) {
            txtID.setEditable(false);
         }
      }

        @Override
      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
         txtID.setEditable(true);
      }
   };

   class RowListener implements ListSelectionListener {
        @Override
      public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
         if (event.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
            if (data[rowIndex][0] == null || data[rowIndex][0] == "") {
               btnEdit.setEnabled(false);
               btnDelete.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
               btnEdit.setEnabled(true);
               btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
            }
         }
      }
   }

   class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  Date date = new Date();

               if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Login")) {
               txtID.setText("");
               txtName.setText("");
               txtCourse.setText("");
               txtProfessor.setText("");
               txtHelp.setText("");
               txtDate.setText(dateFormat.format(date));


               frame1.setTitle("Add Student data"); // title bar name for add
               frame1.setVisible(true);

               } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("EDIT")) {
               txtID.setText(data[rowIndex][0] + ""); 
               txtName.setText(data[rowIndex][1] + ""); 
               txtCourse.setText(data[rowIndex][2] + "");
               txtProfessor.setText(data[rowIndex][3] + "");
               txtHelp.setText(data[rowIndex][4] + "");
               txtDate.setText(data[rowIndex][5] + "");
               txtDate2.setText(data[rowIndex][6] + "");
               txtID.setEditable(false); 
               frame1.setTitle("Enter Student data"); 
               btnAddInput.setActionCommand("Edit2");
               btnAddInput.setText("ACCEPT");

               frame1.setVisible(true); 
            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("DELETE")) {
               int confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "ARE YOU SURE?", "CONFIRM",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

               if (confirm == 0) {
                  rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
                  rowNumber = 0;

                  noOfStudents--;
                  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                     if (rowIndex != i && i <= noOfStudents) {
                        data[rowNumber][0] = data[i][0];
                        data[rowNumber][1] = data[i][1];
                        data[rowNumber][2] = data[i][2];
                        data[rowNumber][3] = data[i][3];
                        data[rowNumber][4] = data[i][4];
                        data[rowNumber][5] = data[i][5];
                        data[rowNumber][6] = data[i][6];


                        rowNumber++;
                     } else if (rowIndex != i && i > noOfStudents) {
                        data[rowNumber][0] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][1] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][2] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][3] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][4] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][5] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][6] = "";

                        rowNumber++;
                     }
                  }
                  if (noOfStudents == 1000) {
                       btnAdd.setEnabled(false);
                   }
                  else {
                       btnAdd.setEnabled(true);
                   }
                  if (noOfStudents == 0) {
                     btnDelete.setEnabled(false);
                     btnEdit.setEnabled(false);
                  } else {
                     btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
                     btnEdit.setEnabled(true);
                  }

                  rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
                  if (data[rowIndex][0] == null || data[rowIndex][0] == "") {
                     btnEdit.setEnabled(false);
                     btnDelete.setEnabled(false);
                  } else {
                     btnEdit.setEnabled(true);
                     btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
                  }

                  table.updateUI();

               }
            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("AddInput")) {

               if (txtID.getText().isEmpty() || txtName.getText().isEmpty()
                        || txtCourse.getText().isEmpty()// /
                        || txtProfessor.getText().isEmpty() || txtHelp.getText().isEmpty()) {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "PLEASE FILL IN THE BLANKS.", "ERROR!",
                  JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
               }
                else {
                  int dup = 0;
                  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                     if (txtID.getText().equals(data[i][0])) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID NUMBER ALREADY EXISTS.", "ERROR!",
                                 JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        dup++;
                     }
                  }
                  if (dup == 0) {
                     rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
                     data[noOfStudents][0] = txtID.getText();
                     data[noOfStudents][1] = txtName.getText();
                     data[noOfStudents][2] = txtCourse.getText();
                     data[noOfStudents][3] = txtProfessor.getText();
                     data[noOfStudents][4] = txtHelp.getText();
                     data[noOfStudents][5] = txtDate.getText();
                     data[noOfStudents][6] = txtDate2.getText();



                     table.updateUI();
                     frame1.dispose();
                     noOfStudents++;
                     if (noOfStudents == 50){
                        btnAdd.setEnabled(false);
                     }
                        else {
                          btnAdd.setEnabled(true);
                      }
                     if (data[rowIndex][0] == null) {
                        btnEdit.setEnabled(false);
                        btnDelete.setEnabled(false);
                     } else {
                        btnEdit.setEnabled(true);
                        btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
                     }
                  }
               }
               table.updateUI();
            }else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Save")){
                try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("Tutor.txt");
            for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
   {
      for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
      {
          out.print(data[i][j]);
          out.print(", ");
      if(j == 6){   
         out.println();
      }
      }     out.flush();

        }} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        }
              } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Logout")) {
               Date date2 = new Date();
                  int confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "ARE YOU SURE?", "CONFIRM",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (confirm == 0) {
                  rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
                  rowNumber = 0;
                  txtDate2.setText(dateFormat.format(date2));
                }
            }
               if (txtID.getText().isEmpty() || txtName.getText().isEmpty()
                        || txtCourse.getText().isEmpty() || txtProfessor.getText().isEmpty()
                        || txtHelp.getText().isEmpty()|| txtHelp.getText().isEmpty()) {
               } else {
                  data[rowIndex][0] = txtID.getText();
                  data[rowIndex][1] = txtName.getText();
                  data[rowIndex][2] = txtCourse.getText();
                  data[rowIndex][3] = txtProfessor.getText();
                  data[rowIndex][4] = txtHelp.getText();
                  data[rowIndex][5] = txtDate.getText();
                  data[rowIndex][6] = txtDate2.getText();


                frame1.dispose();
               }
               table.updateUI();

      }
   }

   class JTextFieldLimit extends PlainDocument {
      private int limit;

      JTextFieldLimit(int limit) {
         super();
         this.limit = limit;
      }

      JTextFieldLimit(int limit, boolean upper) {
         super();
         this.limit = limit;
      }

        @Override
      public void insertString(int offset, String str, AttributeSet attr)
               throws BadLocationException {
         if (str == null) {
                       return;
                   }

         if ((getLength() + str.length()) <= limit) {
            super.insertString(offset, str, attr);
         }
      }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new IAdvise();
   }
}
```

Comment: Ini4j should serve your needs.

Comment: Please state a question

Comment: How can i get my save button to save the array. and how can i get my edit button to fill the grid?